# Assembling 64-bit instructions to raw machine code with nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I want to assemble `64-bit` assembly instructions into raw machine code using `nasm`. If I do, I get an error:

```
error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode
```

Example input:

```
mov rax, 0x12345678
```

Example command:

```
$ nasm input.s -o output
```

[By default, `nasm` uses the bin output format](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.09.09/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.2) which assumes `16-bit`. All the other options seem to support `64-bit` but only when generating full executes/object files and not when generating just the raw machine code.

Is there a way to use the binary format but with `64-bit` instead?

I found another way of accomplishing this task using the `GNU assembler` but I was wondering if you could do the same thing in `nasm` as well.

Comment: Have you added `BITS 64` at the top of your file?

Comment: There's unfortunately no way to do that from the command line in NASM, the default `-f bin` flat binary is only available with `BITS 16` as the default.  I guess you could use a macro and do `nasm -dBITMODE=64` and use `bits BITMODE` in your source to make it easy to try assembling the same code in different modes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting idea. I went ahead and patched NASM to support a `-b` flag for setting the default bitness from the command line. However, I'm short on everyday cases where the `-b` flag would be useful. Any idea? XD

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Good idea.  I forget why I wanted this once.  Probably just to see how a line or two assembled, or to get machine code to hexdump from a quick one-off and easily try it for different modes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `BITS 64` to the top of the assembly source file did the trick.